# "Give up" versus "give in"

Tags: meaning, differences, phrasal-verbs

Do *give up* and *give in* imply different meanings?

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, words don't "imply" but "have" meanings. Please don't use fancy words where they aren't needed.

Comment: @Kim, maybe "have" would have been a better word choice here, but "imply" is not really a fancy word, is it? It means to [express indirectly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imply).

Comment: Wether it's fancy or not surely depends on the context. Compared to "have", "imply" is very fancy. ;)

Comment: How about the use of both in the Florence and the machine song "Never let me go" where by she say she's "its over, i'm going under. I'm not giving up i'm just giving in" describing the fact she's drowning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Give up* and *give in* do have similar meanings that are very close to *surrender*. However, compare the examples of [give up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20up) and [give in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20in) from the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

- don't give up on the project
- forced to give up his job
- refused to give up her efforts
- give in and have some chocolate
- after withstanding hours of begging, their father finally gave in and let them go to the amusement park
- give in his resignation

Notice how the examples of *give in* express something that happens after insistence or entreaty. This doesn't happen in the examples of *give up*, where the meaning is closer to *quit* and *abandon*.

**EDIT:**
It should be noted that the last example of *give in* above ("give in his resignation"), in particular, is actually a case where it means *deliver*, *submit* or *hand in*. It therefore illustrates a definition of *give in* that is very different than *give up*. Another example of *give in* with that meaning, from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/give+in?r=66):

- please give in your timecards

Comment: I think your last example of `give in his resignation` is a different `give in` than the others. In that case, he's just handing something in, which in this case is his resignation.

Comment: @Claudiu, you're right. I'll edit my post to clarify that. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned, `give up` is synonymous with `abandon`; a synonym to `give in` might be `succumb`.

Comment: Was watching Dark Knight and Batman was shouted at - "You can not give in". Was it wrong usage and should have been "You can not give up" ?

Answer (score 6):

**give up** is used for quitting a habit or withdrawing from something.But **give in** is letting something happen or give way for something.

Comment: sorry its 'an important ..

Comment: I think you mean *quiting* (not *quieting*). But , no, importance has nothing to do with the difference between *giving up* and *giving in*. See the other two answers.

Answer (score 1):

Give up indicates cessation as well as forfeiture, whereas give in denotes surrender to something (perhaps temptation in the chocolate example above) or a person or persons (the children in the example of the father above).